# Using one power source for 3 switches

Tags: electrical, wiring

Right when I walk in the door to the house, there are 3 switches. I want to add some can lights and make my switched outlet hot all the time. I want to know how to connect all three switches together so that I can have power to everything. (sorry that the text in the picture is hard to read, and IGNORE the red numbers)

1. I will be installing new can lighting. There is currently no wiring to the switch right now (the orange circles represent lights).
2. There is a porch light (orange) on the second switch, and there are no changes there.
3. The outlet in the garage(green thing with the orange light attached)has no changes.
4. The outlet in the living room has two wires running to it. It was a switched outlet but I don't want it to be anymore. I want to connect the white to the silver screw on the GFCI, and the black to the brass screw on the GFCI, labeling it "No equipment ground".

How do I connect the power source to all of the switches, and the switches to all of the outlets/lights so that they work? Does anyone have a diagram? Thanks!

[image: HomeWiringPlans]

Comment: You can't put GFCI on a switched outlet.

Comment: Can you leave the garage outlet always hot, and run a separate cable to the new exterior light?

Comment: I had an electrician wire the GFCI in the garage. He knew it was on a switch. The whole outlet is either on or off depending on the switch. I just am adding the pole new light. Why shouldn't the GFCI be on a switched outlet?

Comment: @Harper, I know some GFCI'S will trip with a power cycle but not all, other than that do you have a code reference I did a quick look because I did not remember this as a code issue.

Comment: @EdBeal -- it's not a Code issue, more a GFCI-design issue, really.

Comment: Are you running new wires to the garage receptacle, and is this an attached or detached garage?

Comment: If cycling power on a GFCI was a problem, they would all trip on powered outages. I don't think that is an issue.

Comment: @archonOSX , I have installed a new GFCI on a switched bathroom outlet and every time it was cycled that particular brand/model would trip I had several and after the second one I changed brands and the problem was gone.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The garage is detached and already has wire run to it. I am just adding an LED floodlight.

Comment: Also, I have not had any issues with the GFCI tripping in the garage when I turn on and off the switch.

Comment: @FixItJoe -- is the existing wire direct bury, or in a conduit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I misunderstood you. While the garage is not accessible from the house, it is still right next to the house, and therefore wire is ran through the attic into the garage

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GFCI will not make your outlets hot all the time. Your wiring must come directly from the power supply not a switch. You can do this very easily in the 3 gang switch box you have, if you have enough space by bypassing the switches and tying your wires together with wire nuts. Hot wire to hot wire, nuetrals to nuetrals, ground to ground.As for your lights you have to have your wiring from the power supply(panel box) to your switch box.Pigtail your hot wire to each switch (brass screw), pigtail ground wire to each switch (green screw). Tie all your nuetrals together with a wire nut.

Comment: @E BIRD thanks. I had to remove the old outlet box because the GFCI (w/ "No equipment ground") did not fit in the old box. I'm putting in a shallow and wider gang box for the outlet and connecting the black to brass and white to silver on the LINE side. On the other side of the wire, I will disconnect the switch and run it to the power source with pig tails. Then I will connect the switch to another switch to get power for the overhead can lighting.

Comment: Kool man. Let me know how everything works out.